# How to perform data archive in SQL Server with many tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Let's say I have a database with many tables in it. I want to perform data archiving on certain tables, that is create a same table with same structures (same constraint, indexes, columns, triggers, etc) as a new table and insert specific data into the new table from the old table.

Example, current table has data from 2008-2017 and I want to move only data from 2010-2017 into the new table. Then after that, I can delete the old table and rename the new table with naming conventions similar to old table.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Right-click the db and use Generate Scripts.  Click on Advanced on the last screen to include triggers, constraints, etc.

Comment: smoore, I am currently using this method but what is the proper process of data archiving? Do I delete the old table, and keep the new table and rename it to the old table name or just leave it?

Comment: There are different ways.  Mostly you want  INSERT INTO NewTable(col1, col2, etc) SELECT col1, col2, etc FROM OldTable WHERE dateField >= '2010-01-01'

Comment: So the net result is you delete the trailing two years of data?

Comment: Yea for example, i don't want to keep data older than 2015 onwards.

Comment: Can you not just delete out the data older than 2015? I'm not sure where the need for moving data into a separate table, then dropping the old table comes in.

Comment: I thought of that as well but my project manager wants me to do it this way

Comment: I mean deleting data in the table might be slower than inserting data i want to keep into new table. But deleting data might be easier because we don't need to worry about importing table structure(constraint,keys,indexes etc) into new table.

Comment: What are your main concerns here? The main reason to do the sort of copy-rename-drop thing is if you have a huge amount of data, and you can't afford downtime on the table. As a one-time thing, that's not a bad approach (although I'd argue batched deletes could work fine too). If it's something you have to do on a recurring basis, I would look into table partitioning (basically you split a single table into a bunch of sharded tables which get treated like a single table. When you want to remove old data you simply "switch out" the partition you want to delete). It's sort of involved though.

Comment: Well basically my database has over 200 tables more or less. I have to perform data archiving on ,say around 40-50 tables. Some tables have huge amount of data, like 50 000 or so . Again depending on which table I;m dealing with.

Comment: Does that mean if i go with copy rename drop method, say on tableA (old) and tableA_New (new table),  Do i have to drop tableA and then rename back all the conventions in the script for tableA_New to the same ones as tableA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sort of clone-rename-drop logic you're talking about, the basics are pretty straight forward. Really the only time this is a good idea is if you have a table with a large amount of data, which you can't afford down time or blocking on, and you only plan to do this one. The process looks something like this:

1. Insert all the data from your original table into the clone table
2. In a single transaction, `sp_rename` the original table from (for example) `myTable` to `myTable_OLD` (just something to distinguish it from the real table). Then `sp_rename` the clone table from (for example) `myTable_CLONE` to `myTable`
3. Drop `myTable_OLD` when you're happy everything has worked how you want. If it didn't work how you want, just `sp_rename` the objects back.

Couple considerations to think about if you go that route

- Identity columns: If your table has any identities on it, you'll have to use `identity_insert on` then reseed the identity to pick up at where the old identity left off
- Do you have the luxury of blocking the table while you do this? Generally if you need to do this sort of thing, the answer is no. What I find works well is to insert all the rows I need using `(nolock)`, or however you need to do it so the impact of the select from the original table is mitigated. Then, after I've moved 99% of the data, I will then open a transaction, block the original table, insert *just the new data* that's come in since the bulk of the data movement, then do the `sp_rename` stuff

  - That way you don't lock anything for the bulk of the data movement, and you only block the table for the very last bit of data that came into the original table between your original insert and your `sp_rename`
  - How you determine what's come in "since you started" will depend on how your table is structured. If you have an identity or a datestamp column, you can probably just pick rows which came in after the max of those fields you moved over. If your table does NOT have something you can easily hook into, you might need to get creative.

**Alternatives**
A couple other alternatives that came to mind:

**Table Partitioning:**
This shards a single table across multiple partitions (which can be managed sort of like individual tables). You can, say, partition you data by year, then when you want to purge the trailing year of data, you "switch out" that partition to a special table which you can then truncate. All those operations are meta-data only, so they're super fast. This also works really well for huge amounts of data where deletes and all their pesky transaction logging aren't feasible

The downside to table partitioning is it's kind of a pain to set up and manage.

**Batched Deletes:**
If you're data isn't *too* big, you could just do batched deletes on the trailing end of your data. If you can find a way to get clustered index seeks for your deletes, they should be *reasonably* lightweight. As long as you're not accumulating data faster than you can get rid of it, the benefit of this kind of thing is you just run it semi-continuously and it just nibbles away at the trailing end of your data

**Snapshot Isolation:**
If deletes cause too much blocking, you can also set up something like snapshot isolation, which basically stores historical versions of rows in `tempdb`. Any query which sets `isolation level read committed snapshot` will then read those pre-change rows instead of contend for locks on the "real" table. You can then do batched deletes to your hearts content and know that any queries that hit the table will never get blocked by a delete (or any other DML operation) because they'll either read the pre-delete snapshot, or they'll read the post-delete snapshot. They won't wait for an in-process delete to figure out whether it's going to commit or rollback. This is not without its drawbacks as well unfortunately. For large data sets, it can put a big burden on `tempdb` and it too can be a little bit of a black box. It's also going to require buy-in from your DBAs.

Comment: A very informative details. Thanks. But I figured since i am halfway there through this drop and rename method,. I will stick with this. Just a question though, can I do it this way.  I use insert into TableNew....select from Table the data i want to keep. Then do I drop the Table and then proceed to rename the primary key, indexes,triggers etc same as the ones in Table? As i am aware you can't have similar naming convention on two different tables.

Comment: Also, i come across this issue where I can't insert data into the new table from old table as the error states I have "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_EventGroupDetail_EventGroupMaster_New". The conflict occurred in database "Example", table "dbo.EventGroupMaster_New", column 'EventGroupID'. "  How do i fix this?

Comment: Ah right. the constraints. Yeah, you'll have to sp_rename all them as well. That or be content that all your constraints on the new table look like "MyConstraint_Clone"

Comment: Which question are you answering to?

Comment: I was answering your first question about constraints. It sounds like you have quite a bit going on with these tables, which is unfortunately just stuff you're going to have to figure out on your own. These are general guidelines on how to do this, but there are always going to be minutiae specific to your database which you'll have to work with. All I can recommend is you look up info on foreign keys, and specifically that error.